Nothing happens after subprocess.stdout.readline() / subprocess.stdout.read()
From Python, I'm trying to control cmd in console, here is my code:
cmd_process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='cp866')

cmd_process.stdin.write('E:')
cmd_process.stdin.flush()

cmd_process.stdin.write('dir\n')
cmd_process.stdin.flush()

And next, I don't know what to do. If I type:
print(cmd_process.stdout.read())

nothing happens, nothing prints in cmd and cmd console is stuck. So I can't type anything in console and it's like eternal while cycle
If I try:
for i in range(10):
    print(cmd_process.stdout.readline())

print('after for loop')

It actually works fine, and after this for loop, the 'after for loop' is printed. But if I'm typing:
for i in range(1_000):
    print(cmd_process.stdout.readline())

print('after for loop') # <-- won't print and cmd is stuck

It won't work, cmd is stuck.
If I understand documentation right, the reason is the so-called deadlock:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use Popen.communicate() when using pipes to avoid that.
As I understand from Using module 'subprocess' with timeout answers and documentation, there are subprocess.call(), subprocess.check_call() and subprocess.check_output() highter_api commands.
Also, about .call() from documentation:
Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.
questions:

Why .read() doesn't show anything?
How can I overcome deadlock?


The functions call, check_call and check_output are a part of the old API. I wouldn't use them in new code. Are you sure that the function run wouldn't suit your needs better? It is much more user-friendly than the lower-level class Popen.

Soooo can't you os.listdir the directory yourself?

I Googled "cosnolly". Nothing

You are interacting with cmd and it is not finished (it's out stream is not yet closed) so your loop is waiting for next lines. In case the cmd closes (for instance you write('exit\n') after the dir but before your loop, you will see your loop returns empty lines every time you call readline on the closed stream, so you know the command is over.
There is no way to know that dir finished while cmd is still running (other than hacking with timeouts or scanning for expected pattern).
How about running cmd with a sinlge command you want? This way the command finishes and it's stream closes so you can have a clue where you are.
cmd_process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c dir c:\\Windows"], ...

Thanks, I've tried 'exit/n' as well but it didn't work as well, I tried other solutions.
I want to run cmd with more than one command in order to learn how to manage cmd based on the result of the work. For example, the program gave me the result - if the result is one, I do this, if it is different, I do something else.
